# How to implement SSL in rabbitmq with RPC?

Tags: rabbitmq, rpc

I am planning to implement SSL connection with RPC structure in RabbitMQ, where I have RPC server and one RPC client. My understanding is not very clear about the SSL certificate exchange in RabbitMQ. I refered https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html before. My questions are:

1. Do I have to make connection in my RPCServer as well as in RPCClient code?
2. Will RPCServer and RPCClient both act as my RabbitMQ clients? If yes, then will I have to create different certificates for both?

Please help me on this as soon as possible.

Comment: Is there any criteria to follow while putting questions here, so that you can get response?

Comment: Is this question so difficult for experts???

Comment: It's unclear what are you asking, read this firs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask.